# Creating custom file extensions on Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, file

just curious if anyone knows a good tutorial or some info on how to create a custom file type for an application. By default, XCode uses binary for saves (and it's fully functional) but obviously it's better to have a **custom** file type for an application, rather than a binary file. Is this easier said than done?

Comment: Are you referring to Core Data or more generally speaking? File extensions don't dictate the format, they only hint at it and can be completely wrong. What you're asking is how to create your own custom format. To answer that, we need to know whether you're using Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some false starts in earlier releases, Mac OS X 10.3 introduced the concept of Uniform Type Identifiers (UTI) to describe how files are associated with applications.  UTIs try to incorporate all the previous mechanisms, including file extensions, legacy Mac OS file types, MIME types, etc.  Applications can declare UTI information in the app bundle `Info.plist`.  There is an overview in the Apple Developer documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html).  By the way, [not everyone is convinced that UTIs are the best solution](http://arstechnica.com/staff/fatbits/2009/09/metadata-madness.ars).

Comment: Thank you, Ned! That worked perfectly - I'm actually pleasantly surprised at how easy that was